# Why does the ABC has to be placed in the left most position in python abstract class?

Tags: python

Is there any difference in class A and class B in the following code?

```
from abc import ABC

class Base:
  ...

class A(ABC, Base):
  ...

class B(Base, ABC):
  ...
```

I see that most of the code online uses the first version (class A), why is that so?

Comment: You can look at the `__mro__` (**m**ethod **r**esolution **o**rder) of each class to see the difference.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, yes I know the __mro__, in that case, wont class B makes more design sense? since the methods in Base will be searched first. and ABC should be the super base class?

Comment: I guess that it is to give `ABC`'s members precedence over `Base`'s in case of name conflicts.

Comment: Usually when working with abstract base classess, it makes `ABC` methods and attributes priority. (`A will inherit MRO of ABC first and  then MRO of Base`). Basically, to when confilcting method names between `ABC and Base`, ` ABC ` Methods  take precedence.

Comment: @Mox - It depends on the specific requirements of your code and the order in which you want to resolve conflicts between the base classes.

Comment: @Prudhviraj in that case, when there is no conflict in method names, the order should not have mattered. is that correct?

Comment: @Mox  yes, order doesn't matter when there are no conflicts. In such cases, Python MRO based on class hierarchies and will follow `left-to-right` approach. it resolve methods. The order becomes significant mainly when there are name conflicts (for precedence)